# eslintrc.cjs is being ignored by ESLint

Tags: node.js, next.js, frontend, eslint, typescript-eslint

`.eslintrc.cjs` is ignoring the rules I try to off/warn.

I don't know why or how, but yesterday I finished some changes without having any complain from ESLint.

Today, I have a rule popping up and preventing me from building the application, and every time I try to exclude it from my `.eslintrc.cjs` file, it keeps appearing.

The rule itself is `@typescript-eslint/no-floating-promises` (alongside a few others that didn't appear).

When I add it to the file (at least as a warn), it keeps appearing in the editor and when running `npx eslint`.

```
  rules: {
    "@typescript-eslint/no-floating-promises": ["warn"],
    // ... other rules
  }
```

I need some help with this, please! I can't go file by file deactivating this.

I tried deleting `node_modules`, cloning the repo again just in case I touched anything without noticing, installing the extension again, adding the rule in the `eslintrc` file, changing the `estlintrc` file extension, restarting the ESLint server with VSCode...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the issue but you need to export the rules.

```
module.exports = {
  rules: {
    "@typescript-eslint/no-floating-promises": ["warn"],
    // ... other rules
  }
}
```

If you're not doing anything complicated you can also use `.eslint.json` or `.esling.yaml` which might be more intuitive. See the [documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/configuration-files) for more configuration file options.